# Why isn't VirusTotal detecting a zip file that contains malware?

Tags: malware-detection

**Summary**

1. On [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com), I have just used its "Scan a URL" feature to see if it
detects malware within zip files.

I found a test zip file containing malware (I believe), at

https://github.com/ActorExpose/source-code-apk-malware

The actual file containing the malware is

https://github.com/ActorExpose/source-code-apk-malware/archive/refs/heads/main.zip

2. So I pasted the above zip file URL into VirusTotal's url box, and hit ENTER.
But to my surprise, the result showed "0/88: No security vendors flagged this
URL as malicious".

3. **So my questions are:**

a) Does this mean that VirusTotal is not detecting the malware?
b) If not, why not?
c) Or have I chosen a zip file on github that doesn't actually contain malware?
d) If the latter is the case, where can I find a zip file that does contain
malware, so that I can test it on VirusTotal?
e) Is there a reputable site that has such a sample zip file?

**Full Details**

4. Initially, I ran the malware checker [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) on the Firefox
extension visited-color-picker. This is because I was considering downloading
the extension, but Firefox point out that they don't maintain security checks on
it. The extension changes the colour of visited links to the colour of your
choice.

You see, Firefox's own visited links color selector doesn't work satisfactorily
(yes I HAVE selected "Always" in Firefox's Preferences...Colors).

5. The extension visited-color-picker can be downloaded from

https://github.com/william-billaud/visited-color-picker

And the file to download is

https://github.com/william-billaud/visited-color-picker/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

6. So I used VirusTotal's "Scan a URL" feature, and pasted the above URL address
of the zip file into the box.

The result showed "0/88: No security vendors flagged this URL as malicious".

7. But I decided to check if [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) really does detect malware. So I
found what I believe is a zip file containing malware, at

https://github.com/ActorExpose/source-code-apk-malware

The rest is explained in the "Summary" at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Because virus detection software is *far* from perfect? If you think a bit about it, finding out if a program has any particular (malicious or not) effect is essentially the halting problem, that can **not** be solved. Virus detection software uses (very sophisticated) pattern matching techniques to see if some known pattern (of a very large set) indicative of malware is present (like typical code used to infect other files). If the particular malicious piece of code hasn't been seen, it is very unlikely to be detected this way. Some tools check part of the sequence of instructions executed to detect unusual behaviour, and flag that. That is a lot more expensive, however.